# Is the source system typically one of the fields used to uniquely identify business key?

Tags: database-design, best-practices, master-data-services, natural-key, data-vault

One of the key components of designing a data vault is identifying **enterprise-wide unique business keys** ("business key" AKA "natural key").  It's not enough to use `OrderID` to identify records in an `Orders` table, because when you add another orders table from another source system (e.g., a brick-and-mortar store launches an online store), there may well be collisions.

In Data Vault best practices, should one include the name of the source system as one of the fields used to uniquely identify a record, when adding it to a hub table?  Rather than searching for some combination of fields in `Orders` which will *hopefully* be universally unique ({ `CustomerID`, `OrderID`, and `OrderDate` }, maybe), one could identify brick-and-mortar orders with { "Brick-and-Mortar Order System", `OrderID` }, and one could identify online orders with { "Online Order System", `OrderID` }:

[image: Records from two sources flow together into a "hub" table]

This seems like the obvious solution, but I've not seen it mentioned in any of the Data Vault modeling documents I've found, so I wonder if there's some reason not to use this approach.

The Data Vault approach seems to be an outgrowth of Master Data Management practices, so if this is a solved problem in MDM, that solution probably applies here too.

Comment: This isn't a problem specific to DV. If you have external systems that could cause collisions, you need to make the data unique by adding another dimension, which could be your proverbial SourceID (e.g. brick and mortar vs online), or the "hopefully" unique scenario you proposed. I always elect a guaranteed unique outcome.

Comment: @RandolphWest: yes, and that's how I've always handled it, though I've also seen a persuasive case for maintaining a separate synthetic key table for each source system.  I'd like to understand the "official" way of handling this in Data Vault Modeling, though; quite a few things are different, and I don't want my preconceptions to carry the day.

Comment: I'd do a synthetic key myself, given that there's no "natural" system identifier for "online". Look, I get where you're coming from with official ways of doing things, but there's also pragmatism :-)